# How to set / reset dialog radio buttons group?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try to write some script where I could set some parameters before I make call of dialog. There is only one button, OK, and radiobutton group. I planned to change title of dialog before call and also to freely (grammatically) set which radio button is checked. First call, after script is loaded, show dialog with no radiobutton checked, but if I check any of them and then repeat call (press button to call, for example) then dialog appears with earlier selected radio button but returned value is "undefined".
I need this:

1. I wish to programmaticaly set checked any of radiobuttons in dialog before call to open it
2. I wish to be able to reset radiobuttons (checked none) if any of them earlier is checked

I tried some solution I found here and there but no score.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $( "#dialog-oc" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      width: 520,
      resizable:false,
      autoOpen: false,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          var odg=$('input[name="radiooc"]:checked', '#dialog-oc').val();
           $('#dialog-oc input:radio:checked').each(function () {
              $(this).attr('checked', false);
            });
          $("#dialog-oc").dialog("close"); //close dialog
          alert('Answer is '+odg);
        }
      }
    });
});

//open dialog
$("#dialog-oc" ).dialog( "open" );
$('#dialog-oc input:radio').prop('checked', false); //reset radiobuttons
$(".second").attr('checked', false); //reset by using class
//change title of dialog, this works OK:
$("#dialog-oc").dialog("option", "title", "New title");

$( function() {
    $( "input" ).checkboxradio();
    $( "fieldset" ).controlgroup();
});
</script>

<body>
<div class="widget" id="dialog-oc" title="Pick a one">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Pick quantity: </legend>
    <label for="radio-1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiooc" id="radio-1" class="second" value="1">
    <label for="radio-2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiooc" id="radio-2" class="second" value="2">
    <label for="radio-3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiooc" id="radio-3" class="second" value="3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What data do you have to determine which radiobuttons should be `checked` when dialog is opened?

Comment: I'm able to read what radio button is pressed after click on OK button in dialog, but I'm unable to set any of radio buttons before I make call to open dialog. Also, I wish I'm able to reset to uncheck all radio buttons after each call to open the dialog, so that there is no clue what radio button was checked by last call...

Comment: Ok, so on the 1st pass, no radio buttons should be checked. On the 2nd pass, where is the data stored for what was selected?

Comment: checked radio button is possible to read in variable odg, but that's not point here. Why you aks it for?

Comment: Based on your code, when the dialog is closed, the radio buttons are cleared. If you want the radio buttons to be checked, based on what was selected previously, you will need to know what was selected previously. That needs to be readable from someplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help; not sure.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/t0a7uabq/

**HTML**

```
<button id="sel-btn">Select</button>
<div id="dialog-oc" title="Pick a one">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Pick quantity: </legend>
    <label for="radio-1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiooc" id="radio-1" class="second" value="1">
    <label for="radio-2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiooc" id="radio-2" class="second" value="2">
    <label for="radio-3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiooc" id="radio-3" class="second" value="3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-oc").dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 520,
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        var odg = $('#dialog-oc input:checked').val();
        $("#sel-btn").data("sel", $('#dialog-oc input:checked').attr("id"));
        $('#dialog-oc input:radio').each(function() {
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
        $("#dialog-oc").dialog("close"); //close dialog
      }
    },
    open: function(e, ui) {
      if ($('#sel-btn').data("sel") !== null) {
        var mySel = $('#sel-btn').data("sel");
        $("#" + mySel).prop("checked", true);
      }
    }
  });

  //open dialog
  $("#dialog-oc").dialog("open");
  $("#sel-btn").click(function() {
    $("#dialog-oc").dialog("open");
  })
  $('#dialog-oc input:radio').prop('checked', false); //reset radiobuttons
  $(".second").attr('checked', false); //reset by using class
  //change title of dialog, this works OK:
  $("#dialog-oc").dialog("option", "title", "New title");

  $("input").checkboxradio();
  $("fieldset").controlgroup();
});
```

You can make use of the `open` callback to execute code that can set a radio button to `checked`. I made use of the `.data()` feature to store the selected id when the dialog is closed. This way, the same element is set to checked when it opens.

Comment: HEy mate, I tried your example but it doesn't help in my case, but thanks for your effort to help.

Comment: @LudusH what exactly does not work? Or is your example case not like your code? Any errors in console?

Comment: everything is OK, I made some small hardly visible error by adopting your code, but after revision it's now OK. Thanks.